# replacing HTML special characters in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I've created a class named `ServletUtils` which has a method in it that replaces all HTML special characters and looks like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ServletUtils
{
  public static String replaceHTMLSpecialChars(String str)
  {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    char temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
      temp = str.charAt(i);
      if(temp == '<')
      {
          buffer.append("&lt;");
      }
      else if(temp == '>')
      {
          buffer.append("&gt;");
      }
      else if(temp == '"')
      {
          buffer.append("&quot;");
      }
      else if(temp == '&')
      {
          buffer.append("&amp;");
      }
      else
      {
          buffer.append(temp);
      }
    }
    return buffer.toString();
  }

  public static String replaceHTMLSpecialCharsFromFile(String filepath)
  {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    try
    {
      File file = new File(filepath);
      if(file.exists())
      {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        buffer.append(line + "\n");
        }
        br.close();             
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("File doesn't exist: " + filepath);
      }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){fnfe.printStackTrace();}
    catch(IOException io){io.printStackTrace();}

    return replaceHTMLSpecialChars(buffer.toString());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(ServletUtils.replaceHTMLSpecialCharsFromFile("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 7.0\\webapps\\jed_1.1\\jsp\\server_processing.jsp"));
  }

}
```

Testing it with the main method certainly works, but from a JSP page, when I call:

```
<textarea rows="25" cols="110" readonly="readonly">
<%
  String contextPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
  ServletUtils.replaceHTMLSpecialCharsFromFile(contextPath + "jsp\\server_processing.jsp");
%>
</textarea>
```

I get a blank textarea.  I know the `ServletUtils` methods work. So why am I not able to load the textarea in the JSP page with the results?  Please advise.

Comment: What happens if you put an extra \\ before `jsp\\server_processing.jsp` ?

Comment: May I suggest you use an escape function from a library instead of rolling your own? https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4(java.lang.String)

Comment: Nothing happens.  The contextPath ends with a \ anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The last line in your scriptlet does evaluate to the string you want, but nothing is printing the string.

The JSTL core [`out`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) tag does what you want, and will also do the HTML entity escapes for you (so you don't need the `replaceHTMLSpecialChars` method).

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<%
String contextPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
String text = contextPath + "jsp\\server_processing.jsp";
%>

<textarea rows="25" cols="110" readonly="readonly">
    <c:out value="${text}"/>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [JSTL fn:escapeXml() Function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_escapexml.htm) that escapes characters that can be interpreted as XML markup. There is no need to replace the HTML special characters.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...

<c:set var="text" value="<html><head><body></body></head></html>"/>
<textarea>${fn:escapeXml(text)}</textarea>
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I figured it out. All I had to do was use the JSP *out* like so:

```
<textarea rows="25" cols="110" readonly="readonly">
<%
  out.print(ServletUtils.replaceHTMLSpecialCharsFromFile(contextPath + "jsp\\server_processing.jsp"));
%>

</textarea>
```

Comment: Avoid Scriplets intead use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)